# Using excel how to generates line string of circle if i know the center and the diameter

Tags: excel, maps

How using excel if know the center of circle and the diameter, how to generate the line strings, which i will use to upload on map to draw circles
Example center is 24.75815, 46.66208 , diameter is 350 meter , line strings will be (46.688051 24.69508 0.0, 46.687969 24.696089 0.0, 46.687722 24.697076 0.0, ...........)
there is websites generates like [circle generator](https://www.scottmurray.me/kml/circle/index.php) it but i need large number cannot do one by one
i am sure that can be made by excel as it is linear calculation.